# How to use a previously created View file inside the application?

Tags: swift, xcode, file, swiftui

Inside Xcode, I follow File-> New -> File -> SwiftUI View and create a UIView File. It creates an editable file with the code below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyImageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
struct MyImageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyImageView()
    }
}
```

After I do the desired edits, I want to use this View inside my application. I created new View inside Storyboard, but inside the Identity Inspector for this View, inside custom class section I cannot find the name MyImageView. I don't know how to hook up the newly storyboard created View with the MyImageView of the UIView File. Can you help please?

Comment: Your `MyImageView` is a `View`, not an `UIImageView`. You should lookup how to use `UIHostingController` to display SwiftUI views in UIKit.

Comment: I updated the post according to View for the place of imageview. So can you explain now?